# Connecting a wireless webcam and wireless dongle

Tags: linux, wifi, camera

I must create a wireless connection between a USB wireless  dongle (DLink wireless-N USB Mini Adapter DWA-140) and a wireless webcam (DLink DCS-932L). I.e. point to point connection without Internet.

I have to use Linux without a GUI (only commands).

What do I need to do, to get this to work?

Comment: which Linux distro where you are connecting your USB wireless dongle ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the camera setup will ask you to connect to an access point. If that is the case, setup your Linux box with hostapd. The following is the hostapd.conf I use at home for a wireless access point:

```
driver=nl80211  #the driver appropriate for your card
interface=wlan0 #the interface name assigned to your card
bridge=br0      #unless br0 is already used

#802.11n stuff
hw_mode=g       # wireless-g support
ieee80211n=1    # wireless-n on top of wireless-g
wmm_enabled=0   # I disable WMM because it is satan, YMMV
ht_capab=[HT20][SHORT-GI-20][RX-STBC1] #needed for wireless-n, you may want to comment this out to start

## 802.11n EOF


channel=2       #channel
country_code=US #must match your driver I believe


ssid=SkyNet     #use what you want

# this is WPA security, supposed to support just about anything including iOS devices (confirmed)
auth_algs=3
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=lamaison
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
macaddr_acl=0

# this may provide you with more stats, but might just be better to comment out for starting your project
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
```